# Equivalent of TagUtils.getInstance().lookup() Struts1 in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts, taglib, struts-1

I have this function  in Struts 1:

```
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag#doStartTag()
 */
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {

    Carac carac = (Carac) TagUtils.getInstance().lookup(pageContext, name, property, scope);
    // Code here
    return SKIP_BODY;
}
```

and I am trying to create the same tag in Struts 2 but don't know what's the purpose of this:

```
TagUtils.getInstance().lookup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to get my object from the view to the tag in struts 2 :

my tag :

```
<%@ taglib uri="wells/taglib/produit" prefix="produit"%>

         <produit:produitPhoto prod="row" />
```

Here is how t can get it:

```
  getStack().findValue(this.prod, Produit.class); // return Object Produit
```

Ref : [Class TagUtils](http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/TagUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Precisely what [the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/apidocs/org/apache/struts/taglib/TagUtils.html#lookup%28javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says: it returns the named bean's property from the provided scope.

Comment: thanks for the response ,but how can i translate it to struts 2. i really didn't get how .

Comment: @Nabs It'd be easiest to start with any of the S2 tags and work from there. They subclass the ContextBeanTag to provide easy access to params and the value stack. You could also consider implementing a JSP-based tag or doing more work outside of the servlet framework.