# TagUtils.lookup(PageContext,String,String,String) equivalent in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts, struts-1

I'm migrating an application from Struts1 to Struts2.
It is using following:

```
o = (DataObject) RequestUtils.lookup(super.pageContext, name,
                                           replaceIndicies(dataObject), null);
```

but the lookup function is not in V2 of the API.
Is there equivalent method in Struts2? If not what i need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of TagUtils.getInstance().lookup() Struts1 in Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056722/equivalent-of-tagutils-getinstance-lookup-struts1-in-struts-2)

Comment: In the link provided for the document, the document does not exist. Please provide me a valid link.

Comment: You might also find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24452502/573032) you could use to answer your question. Also you didn't tell us where and how this code is used.

Comment: The link to the tag utils docs in answer pointed to be Aleksandr M is dead and it was for V1 of the API -- the function in question is not present in V2

Comment: Pare it down to just the question

Comment: @JohnHascall S1 and S2 are totally different frameworks. Accepted answer of linked question shows what's need to be done.